# Installing cli tools for hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I get that error when trying to install cli tools, I set up python version to 2.7 and I installed node-gyp but it didn't help

users-Air:~ user$ npm install -g composer-cli@0.20

/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/bin/composer -> /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/cli.js

> dtrace-provider@0.8.7 install /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/dtrace-provider
>
> node-gyp rebuild || node suppress-error.js

gyp ERR! configure error

gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "/path/to/executable/python2.7", you can set the PYTHON env variable.

gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)

gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder. (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)

gyp ERR! stack     at F (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)

gyp ERR! stack     at E (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)

gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16

gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5

gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5

gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)

gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.5.0

gyp ERR! command "/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/bin/node" "/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"

gyp ERR! cwd /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/dtrace-provider

gyp ERR! node -v v10.13.0

gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0

gyp ERR! not ok

> fsevents@1.2.4 install /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/fsevents
>
> node install

[fsevents] Success: "/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node" already installed

Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile

> node-report@2.2.1 install /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/node-report
>
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error

gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "/path/to/executable/python2.7", you can set the PYTHON env variable.

gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)

gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder. (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)

gyp ERR! stack     at F (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)

gyp ERR! stack     at E (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)

gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16

gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5

gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5

gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)

gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.5.0

gyp ERR! command "/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/bin/node" "/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"

gyp ERR! cwd /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/node-report

gyp ERR! node -v v10.13.0

gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0

gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! node-report@2.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the node-report@2.2.1 install script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2018-11-01T16_00_13_969Z-debug.log

Comment: hi there, you need to check you meet all the pre-reqs here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html  - You're using Node 10 and it is not supported by Hyperledger Composer - check the docs for the exact Node editions supported and use `nvm` to install a supported Node version

Comment: The answer was deleted and I can't point you to the other stackoverflow because the top answer is not a good solution to the problem. So what you need to do in a command window is 1) nvm install 8. 2) nvm use 8. Now you can install composer again. The reason is that node 10 has gone LTS and the prereqs-ubuntu script installs the lts version which means node 10 is currently being installed

Answer (score 1):

You are using `node js` version `10.x.x`, which is not supported by Hyperledger.

Please install `node js` version **`8.x.x`**.

It will solve your problem.

> **Note:** Make sure that you are installing **composer tools** as **non-root**
>   user. Install composer tools **without sudo**.